# How to update image when image changed on server with SDWebImage

Tags: ios, sdwebimage

I have static URL of image but when I edit that image and go back to main screen then image is not changed it still taking old image from cache.

Is there any way to update image in cache?

Comment: You manually change the picture from your app?

Comment: yes i m changing image from app and upload it on server.

Comment: How you getting image from the url show me?

Comment: [self.imgProfilePic sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",ServerPath,userObj.profilePicture]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"profile_placeholder"] options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];

Comment: When you edit the picture at that time try to clear the cache 
[[SDImageCache sharedImageCache]imageCache clearMemory];
    [[SDImageCache sharedImageCache]imageCache clearDisk];

Answer (score 0):

On the [SDWebImage documentation](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage#handle-image-refresh), the guys gives the piece of code to do what you need:

```
[imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/olivier.poitrey/picture"]
             placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar-placeholder.png"]
                      options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];
```

Comment: yes i did the same but still i m not getting refresh image.